# Removing a port number from a string

Tags: php

How do you remove the port number from a url string? For example:

```
$string = "http://www.url.com:88";
```

or

```
$string = "http://www.url.net:88";
```

and so on.

I tried:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ":", 0));
```

but that removes the first ":" and not the second.

Comment: what language do you try removing the port? why do you need the port to be removed?

Comment: @Iancey Your try will fail becuase there is more than one `:` char in string. Try using regex. `preg_replace("\:\d+", "", "http://www.url.com:88");` .[Pattern explanation on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/oZ6bM6/5)

Comment: regex or strrpos not strpos (http://php.net/manual/de/function.strrpos.php)
So this should work :
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ":", 0));

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use parse_url for that.

```
$urlParts = parse_url("http://www.url.net:88");
print_r($urlParts);
```

this will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.url.net
    [port] => 88
)
```

then unset the port with unset($urlParts['port']) and glue it back together.

Also see http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: FYI, `parse_url()` can behave in unexpected ways when the hostname is an IPv6 address. A scheme needs to be prepended in order for it to work, and in some cases it will return `false` for valid IPs, and in others it will incorrectly think the last octet is the `port`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ":", 0));
```

The function strrpos() searches for the last occurrence of ":" in the string. But this will only work if there is really a port number in the URI.
Better use a regex:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\:[0-9])+$/', '', $string)
```

Comment: Thanks wordked for me i deleted the port easily.

Answer (score 1):

ReGex fashion :)

```
$urlWithoutPort = preg_replace('/:[0-9]+/', '', 'http://www.url.net:');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's constant port 88

```
$string = substr($string, 0, -3);
```

or **ELSE** by `explode()`

```
$explode = explode(":", $string);
$strings = $explode[0].$explode[1];
```

Comment: port is from 1 digit to 5 !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pythonic way..

1. Find first occurrence
2. Find second occurrence
3. Extract substr

---

```
$string = "http://www.url.net:88";
$first = strpos($string, ":", 0);
$second = strpos($string, ":", ($first+1));
$string = substr($string,0,$second);
echo $string;
```